# Excel count cells based on the values they begin with

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple cells where the first three values are the same but they end with different values, e.g.

`A123-London-5`

`A123-Paris-2`

`A456-Texas_1`

In the above example, the formula should return 2 for the first two and 1 for the thrid one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is in column A, you can count matches on the first four characters with

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,LEFT(A1,4)&"*")
```

Comment: To clarify for OPs understanding:  The asterisk (`*`) is a Wildcard, which means "and any other text".  So, `=COUNTIF(A:A, "1234*")` means "Count how many cells start with 1234", while `=COUNTIF(A:A, "*1234")` would mean "Count how many cells *end* with 1234", and `=COUNTIF(A:A, "*1234*")` would mean "Count how many cells contain 1234 *anywhere* in the text"

Answer (score 1):

Assumes your data is from A2 to A100, alter as needed.

```
=COUNT(IF(LEFT(A$2:A$100,4)=A2,A$2:A$100,””))
```

Commit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Disclaimer: typed this on my phone, didn’t test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A100,3)=LEFT(A1,3)))
```